# Where Is The .emacs file in Windows 8.1?

Tags: microsoft-windows

Hi all so last night I started using Emacs and I enjoyed it. Now I am looking to customize the look to the solarized port of Emacs. Now question is where is the `.emacs` file in windows 8.1?  I have heard many answers to this question, I put my Emacs in `C:\Emacs`.  So any ideas?

Comment: Run Emacs and then do `M-: (getenv "HOME")`. This will output the location of home directory, which is the directory where you can put `.emacs` file or any other kind of init file.

Comment: From stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows

Comment: See [`(emacs) Windows HOME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html) and [`(efaq-w32) Location of init file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html).

Answer (score 2):

From inside Emacs, you can find out the path and file name with this command:

```
C-h v user-init-file RET
```

Newer installations generally default to ~/.emacs.d but some custom installs put it in roaming or dropbox folders.

Comment: You say "default to ~/.emacs.d" but that seems to bring us back to the original question of where is "~/.emacs(.d)"

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to know: just do `C-x C-f ~/.emacs RET` and you'll be looking at the content of the file (most likely empty if you haven't done that earlier), which you can then edit and save.

Once in it, you can use `M-x pwd RET` to know in which directory it is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is located in your `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%` dir. However, any of the following(those are already mentioned above, just summarizing here) can be used to find out the exact location:

1. Type `C-h v user-init-file RET`. This will open a help window which
   will have the location of the init file. Type `C-x 1` or `C-x k
   *Help* RET` to close the popup window.
2. Run the eval command with `M-: (getenv "HOME") RET` which will also
   give the init file location. Don't forget the parentheses because it
   is a lisp expression.

Thanks.