# I can't find my emacs init.el file in the normal paths

Tags: init-file, help

I can't find the init.el file in the normal paths that is supposed to be, and I already try to search inside the emacs app and with the terminal. Apart from that I can write and save files. I made a search to see if there is any init.el file with the basic stuff that already comes with the emacs, but I couldn't find. I need the init.el file because I need to add a meta key for the hash in mac with uk keyboard. I already know how to make a init.el file, but I go to the internet to get the source code, but until now it was not possible to add the meta key to add the hash. If possible could you give me some link to get the init.el file that already comes with emacs. If necessary I can take screenshots.

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Is The .emacs file in Windows 8.1?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/where-is-the-emacs-file-in-windows-8-1)

Comment: You need to (1) find out how to use StackExchange sites - how to ask a question, what's the difference between an answer and a question, etc. (2) *ask Emacs* such questions: (a) `M-x apropos init-file`, (b) `C-h r`, then `i init file`.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs doesn't come with a user init file. You write your own. If there's no user init file, Emacs behaves in the same way as if there's an empty init file, so there's no need for a default init file.

There are [several possible locations for the init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File). If you don't have one already, you can use whichever you want.

To make sure that you don't have an init file yet, check the value of the variable `user-init-file` (`C-h v user-init-file RET`). If this points to an existing file, edit that file. If it doesn't, edit that file or any of the other possible locations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the file if it doesn't exist.

If you want a decent start, [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org) is one possibility.

Comment: I wouldn't call spacemacs a “decent start”. Just someone's preference.

Comment: @Gilles Changed the wording.